# Running a windows APP on MAC

Tags: windows, delphi, macos, cross-platform

I just done a presentation to a client of mine of a commercial windows application I just made available. The problem is that this client just has Mac machines. I don’t know the Mac OS version.

So how can run this APP on Mac?

This APP is created in Delphi 2007 Win32.

What solutions do I have available?

Comment: Why are you presenting a Windows app to a Mac shop?

Comment: Have a look at winebottler http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/

Comment: I did not know they had MAC. But they new the APP has winBased. They loved it, but do not want to switch back to windows.

Comment: Embarcadero are working on a Mac version of Delphi. It's got a way to go and even when it is released, you'll need a bit of work porting it as the VCL won't exist in the same form as on Windows.

Comment: I am in a very similar situation to the OP - I have Delphi 2007- and 2010-based applications and sometimes I come across Mac customers. I just set them up with VMWare Fusion and a copies of Windows 7. The networking etc is fine - some of my apps have client-server databases (Firebird, SQL Server) and these work fine with several VM PCs all sharing data etc exactly as if they were real PCs. The virtual stuff is incredibly impressive (if you haven't already seen it), and it works great on the Mac.

Comment: Macs -only-?  **Dude.. Run!**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For commercial quality deployments, I would only look at VMWare fusion.  Your clients can run Windows on their macs, inside a VM, and run your App inside that VM.  Parallels is okay, but VMWare fusion is head and shoulders higher than everything else out there.  I currently use VMWare fusion heavily, with delphi apps I wrote myself, and it works great for me.

WINE is cool, but I wouldn't support it commercially, as a single-person shop, or small shop, the technical depth of the problems involved in fixing glitches caused by a WINE-and-your-vertical-market application don't make business sense. If your time is worth money, just go with a full windows VM solution, and forget about WINE.

You should also be aware that a cross platform Delphi that targets Mac OS X is also in the works.

P.S. As the other answers above state, your clients would have to pay for a VMWare Fusion license per machine, plus a copy of Windows, per machine.

P.P.S. It has been pointed out to me that <strike>draconian</strike> new rules apply to the use of Windows 7, on virtual machines.

P.P.P.S. I have just learned directly from a Microsoft person familiar with the licensing, that a Full Packaged Product (FPP) Windows 7 license can be used on one machine, or one VM instance, such as VMWare Fusion on your Mac, and that this is fully legal, and that Microsoft has no problems with this.

Comment: In your experience with VM Fusion those it allow networking? Between VM machines?
Or could we install a firebird server on MAC and have the VM machines connect to it?

Comment: I just saw some Parallels vs VM Fusion, and they all say Parallels is much faster.
The price is more or less the same

Comment: @Jlouro - After each release of their software, one of them is faster than the other at SOME THINGS; this is constantly changing. You can waste a lot of time and effort trying to figure out which is faster (I have done in the past). Then you realise that unless you are developing games, the difference in general speed between the 2 is going to be largely irrelevant (and changes from version to version). I would pick one and stick with it. I chose VMWare because it was easy for me to give VMs to people using VMware on PCs and Linux, but you might have other reasons for picking Parallels.

Comment: I'd absolutely go with VMWare for something like this, simply because I've been using VMWare for a loooong time, and my development machine is a "VMWare" virtual machine. But for deployment to clients there are problem with the Windows licensees: AFAIK the "Retail" and "OEM" versions of Windows are not allowed on VMs, the only ones that are allowed on VMs are the ones bought with Volume Licenses or MSDN.

Comment: Why are retail and OEM windows licenses not allowed on VMs?  I have never read any such thing anywhere. Can you state an MS source for that Cosmin?

Comment: @Warren P .. see my answer below with the link to the MS Windows 7 licensing for Virtual machines.  Legally there are restrictions on the OS running under VM's.

Comment: @Peter M:  Wow. That's a shocker.  Thanks for the good information.

Comment: Okay. Not exactly easy to understand from the sources linked, but I have JUST spoken to a Microsoft senior person who assures me that FPP (fully packaged product) licenses can be used on exactly one PC, or on a single VM instance on your Mac for instance, without any legal issue.  That means obviously that running 300 copies of that VM isn't legal, or taking a Retail copy that is also running your PC and making a VM with it isn't fair. But this seems completely fair and reasonable to me; Buy a FPP license for your VMWare/mac.

Answer (score 10):

Run it using a Wine/VirtualBox/VmWare/Bootcamp/Parallels?
Delphi 2007 isn't directly portable to Mac

Answer (score 6):

WINE.

http://wiki.winehq.org/MacOSX

Comment: Cool for messing around. But would you really deploy a business critical application on top of wine and just trust everything to work?

Comment: @Warren Why not? Crossover Office springs to mind. A Windows app running through Wine on a Mac might feel somewhat out of place.

Comment: Isn't Crossover just Wine with commercial support? If that's so, unless your application is on the `supported list`, I guess this applies: `Q: Runs all Windows applications? A: No. Wine runs some Windows applications well, some so-so, and some not at all.`. The quote is from: http://www.codeweavers.com/products/differences/, from the "Corssover" column. Would you, as a developer, consider that a "supported platform"?

Answer (score 3):

**Windows 7 Licensing in Virtual Environments**

From the MS site [Licensing for Virtual Environments](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/about-licensing/virtualization.aspx#tab=3) see the link (.DOCX) [licensing windows7 with VM technologies](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/d/4/3d42bdc2-6725-4b29-b75a-a5b04179958b/licensing_windows7_with_VM_technologies.docx)

Comment: Ouch. Good info. Thanks.  But, does anyone else think Microsoft crossed the line from self-serving to annoyingly evil here? I see what they're doing. They're trying to prevent you from making a homebrew VMWare ESX Server, running 300 instances of Windows desktop, without paying them big coin.  Do they care about single user instances like MacOS with VMWare? No.  Technically end users are incapable of complying with these draconian enterprise rules.

Comment: @Warren P .. well MS's licensing is better than Apples ;-)

Comment: True, there is in fact, an apple logo and a picture of Steve Jobs, right there in the dictionary, beside the word Draconian.   MS only wishes they could be that draconian and not lose all their customers.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into CrossOver from CodeWeavers: http://www.codeweavers.com/products/crossover/

This is basically a commercial version of Wine with many advanced features beyond the free Wine as well as excellent support from CodeWeavers.

The also offer valuable services to help if there are problems with running your application as is under Crossover: http://www.codeweavers.com/services/engagements/

The disadvantage of any VM based solution is obviously that your customer would have to buy windows licenses and licenses for the VM solution for all their machines and then basically end up having to maintain 2 OSs on each machine, MacOSX and the Windows installation in the VM.

Comment: Have you ever deployed a commercial software solution to customers using this? Would you? I wouldn't.

Comment: A college of mine has and is very satisfied with the result.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Lazarus](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/) | [Lazarus for Delphi Users](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Lazarus_For_Delphi_Users). It supports the creation of self-standing graphical and console applications and runs on Linux, FreeBSD, MacOSX and Windows.

Comment: Yes it’s interesting. But for this case I would have to maintain 2 projects. For now it's not an option, I will take a closer look at this in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new product that allows you to compile 
VCL applications for Mac http://www.crossvcl.com.
The problem is that third party component support is limited.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 is the most current and I believe the most convenient version of MS Windows. If you intend to use any of the virtualization software like VirtualBox, Wine, Parallels, VMWare, to run a Windows application in a Mac/OS/X (the host machine), bear in mind that you will still need the Windows 7 CD/license (or XP CD) to install/mount Windows as a virtual machine (the guest machine).

I have installed VirtualBox (free) on my MacBook and then I installed Windows XP on it and Windows runs nice and easy; for home use I think this is fantastic but wouldn't be so sure for commercial use. For commercial use I would go with either Parallels or VMWare because of the support that you can get, but only you know about your requirements.

The price for a license of these VMs may very well beat the price of a Windows computer but, remember that a new Windows computer may be the most straight forward alternative for you and your client.

Hope this helps answer your concerns. Good luck!